# Creating a List of List<objects> from an array of objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, select

Given an array of:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

How can I create a List of `List<Objects>` (`List<List<Object>>`) or an array of `List<Objects>` using `.Select<>` or `.Orderby<>` or any other method, on the ID field?

My initial array will have multiple ID's with the same timestamps. I want to process each ID separately.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Are you trying to group them based on timestamp?

Comment: Are you wanting to group by `ID` so you have a list where each item is a list of `Object` that have the same `ID`?

Comment: I would have thought "on the ID field" would have specified what I was trying to group by,  that but I guess I was mistaken. I think @jeff got it better than me.

Comment: Calling your object an Object is certainly not a good thing to do.  Give it a better name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to *group* the objects by ID, in which case you can do:

```
var groups = objects.Groupby(o => o.ID)
                    .Select(g => g.ToList());
```

Which will give you a "collection" of `List<Object>` that you can iterate over.  If you *really* want a list of lists or an array of lists just add `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to the final query.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very specific

```
List<Object> ListObect = ArrayOject.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby(v=vs.110).aspx) method to group the list by items with the same ID:

```
var groupedByID = originalList.GroupBy(x => x.ID);
```

Technically this returns a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Object>>`, but `IGrouping` can be iterated over just like a list or array. You usually only need a `List` if you need index access, or need to dynamically add/remove items.

Answer (score -1):

See if this helps

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] input = {
                "123, 1/1/2016, 456\n",
                "456, 1/2/2016, 456\n",
                "789, 1/3/2016, 456"
            };
            List<MyObject> objects = input.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).Select(y => new MyObject() {ID = int.Parse(y[0]), timeStamp = DateTime.Parse(y[1]), value = int.Parse(y[2])}).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class MyObject
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
}
```